# Dynamically Add Columns .rdlc

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, rdlc

Using Visual Studio 2013, is there anyway to create dynamic reports that allow the addition of unknown columns?

I'm creating a report that will show different columns per user with a possible limit of up to 8 columns. Is there a way to set some kind of variable column as a placeholder that if not in use, hide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `RDLC` you can't dinamically add/remove columns.

In this case I would use an 8 columns `DataTable` filled at runtime depending on user and 8 `ReportParameter` to store the column name.

If a column name is nothing then set `TableColumn` `Hidden` property to `True`.